# Error installing pandas and quandl via pip - windows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pip, quandl

Goodmorning, I'm trying installing pandas and quandl. I used `pip install quandl` and `pip install pandas` but the feedback is for both:

```
Command "C:\Python34\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\tomsa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-m2kos9k2\\pandas\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\tomsa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-q2r4p42_-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\tomsa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-m2kos9k2\pandas\
```

I tried not to use cached files but it doesn't work anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Solved installing them manually from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pandas) via

```
pip install pandas‑0.20.3‑cp34‑cp34m‑win_amd64.whl
```

in the directory (normally X:\Users\Download in windows if the wheel has not been moved somewhere else)